# How to show confirmed invintations in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have model Invintation, and model Company, the company can send messages to each other only after confirmation of the invitation for messaging.

Invintation.rb

```
class Invintation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'Company', foreign_key: 'recipient_id'
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'Company', foreign_key: 'sender_id'
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'author_id'
end
```

Company.rb

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_companies
  has_many :users, through: :users_companies
  has_many :sent_messages, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: 'sender_id'
  has_many :incoming_messages, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: 'recipient_id'
  has_many :sent_invitations, class_name: 'Invintation', foreign_key: 'sender_id'
  has_many :invitation_recipients, through: :sent_invitations, source: :recipient
  has_many :incoming_invitations, class_name: 'Invintation', foreign_key: 'recipient_id'
  has_many :invitation_senders, through: :incoming_invitations, source: :sender
end
```

On the form I want show companies who confirmed invitation

```
<%= form_for([@company, @message]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :subject, placeholder: "тема" %>
  <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.collection_select :recipient_id, @recipients, :id, :name, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

So i add to controller this code

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    @message = @company.sent_messages.new
    @recipients = @company.invitation_recipients.where(confirm: true)
  end

  def create
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    @message = @company.messages.build(mess_params)
    @message.author_id = current_user
    @message.sender_id = @company.id
    if @message.save
      flash[:success] = "Документы успешно отправлены"
      redirect_to inbox_path(@company)
    end
  end
end
```

but i dont know how i can show in @recipients only confirmed companies, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the most efficient way but I would have a model for invitations and a model for linked companies. When a company invites another company an invitation is created. When the other company accepts the invitation is destroyed and a link between companies is created. Then only show companies the option to receive messages from linked companies.